# How can I run Eclipse SWT applications in a browser as WebAssembly?

Tags: java, swt, webassembly

Is there a way to run Eclipse SWT applications in a webrowser as WebAssembly? CheerpJ v3.0 looks promising. Sadly it only supports Java 8 and SWING/AWT so far, not Eclipse SWT and it's not coming short term. According to them the issue is that solutions like Eclipse SWT don't use Java primarily but relay on JNI calls and thus it's more difficult. I checked for different alternatives to CheerpJ v3.0 but they all have different limitations that look like they don't work for this use case. Maybe I'm looking online for the wrong keywords.

Can someone provide a suggestion for this use case?

Comment: If you are asking for a tool or library, not that such recommendations are off topic.

Comment: SWT is essentially a quite thin layer over the native GUI controls for a particular platform - the underlying code is completely different on each platform. A WebAssembly version would have to be a complete rewrite for this new platform. Have you looked at [Eclipse RAP](https://github.com/eclipse-rap) which uses the SWT API.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the explanation and good hint regarding Eclipse RAP. Feel free to write your comment as a reply and I will accept it as the solution for this case. I think this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT is essentially a thin layer over the native GUI controls for a particular platform - the underlying code is completely different on each platform. A WebAssembly version would have to be a complete rewrite for this new platform, as far as I know this is not being considered.

[Eclipse RAP](https://eclipse.dev/rap/) [github](https://github.com/eclipse-rap) uses the SWT API for a Web UI